# Why is conditional hyperlink result not blue and underlined in excel?

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I want to replace the N/A part with a column value and retain other hyperlinks as they are.

I made a new column for this using:

`=IF(ISERROR(D3),C3,HYPERLINK("[Dict.xlsx]A_Details!A"&MATCH(TRIM(C3),A_Details!A:A,0),C3))`

It works well but the hyperlinks aren't **blue and underlined** for the false part.

Also,I don't want the true part to be hyperlinked.

Comment: I get the same behavior here.  I think Excel only does the formatting for a "pure" `HYPERLINK` in a cell with nothing else.  You can add some conditional formatting with the same condition: `ISERROR` and apply the blue and underline.